# Select rows of table 1 when sum of colA grouped by ID is bigger than sum of colB in table 2 grouped by ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

We have a table of our sold items, it looks like this : ( Table A )

| id | sell_id | item | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 5 | A | 3000 |
| 12 | 5 | B | 2000 |
| 13 | 6 | A | 5120 |
| 14 | 7 | C | 5000 |

and a table where shipped items are placed that looks like this : ( Table B )

| id | sub_id | item | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | A | 2850 |
| 2 | 11 | A | 150 |
| 3 | 12 | B | 2100 |

( Table B is matched to Table A by referencing TableA.id in Table B as sub_id ).

I want to find rows that sum of amount per TableA.id is not equivalent of sum of TableB.amount per TableB.sub_id.

In other words I want to know which sold items are not shipped exactly as the amount which is sold.

I've tried left joining tableA to tableB but i cannot get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show your current query with the Join as you mentioned, and what exactly is not working so we can help you improve it.

Comment: "sum of amount per TableA.id" - `id` is not  a PK of `TableA`, is it?

Comment: So item in table b is redundant?

Comment: @Serg id and sell_id are both pk

Comment: @Strawberry It's to clarify about our table design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM b
                   WHERE a.id = b.sub_id
                   GROUP BY b.sub_id
                   HAVING a.amount = SUM(b.amount) )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b13c67b6e622a5da72f63074d53d423

Comment: @KiarashRzg Fiddle added.

Comment: removed the initial ! sign in HAVING clause and it works!
You just saved my day. @Akina